# Hide the iframes whose content get blocked by proxy

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, proxy

I have a webpage with iframes. 
These iframes are for showing some external website data.

But problem arise when those external servers get blocked in a network it gives a error that "The proxy server is refusing connections". 
It does not look good to me.

I want to hide all these blocked iframes or want to show some alternate data there.

Comment: unfortunately you can't access an iframe's content unless it serves content from the same domain as the parent window

Comment: @Vlad - But is there any way to check whether the content of iframe has been loaded or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to check whether a page has *not* loaded. However, it's possible to use `onload` event handlers.

It's important to not rely on JQuery, because JQuery is also an external source which has to be loaded. Add this code within `<script>` tags **after** the last IFRAME element (often, at the end of the body). Code:

```
//Cannot rely on JQuery, as it has to be loaded
(function(){//Anonymous wrapper.
    var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
    var num_frames = iframes.length;
    //Function to add Event handlers
    var addLoad = window.addEventListener ? function(elem, func){
        elem.addEventListener("load", func, true);
    } : window.attachEvent ? function(elem, func){
        elem.attachEvent("onload", func);
    } : function(elem, func){
        elem.onload = func;
    };
    var success_load = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<num_frames; i++){
        addLoad(iframes[i], function(){
            this.dataSuccessfullyLoaded = true;
            success_load++;
        });
    }
    addLoad(window, function(){
         if(success_load < num_frames){
             for(var i=num_frames-1; i>=0; i--){
                 if(!iframes[i].dataSuccessfullyLoaded){
                     iframes[i].parentNode.removeChild(iframes[i]);
                     //Or: iframes[i].style.display = "none";
                 }
             }
         }
    });
})();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3vnrg/

*EDIT*
Your proxy seems to send HTTP pages with status code 200. Another option is to include the CSS file, and check whether a CSS variable exists or not:

```
/*From http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yb/r/CeiiYqUQjle.css*/
#facebook .hidden_elem{display:none !important}
#facebook .invisible_elem{visibility:hidden}
```

HTML:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yb/r/CeiiYqUQjle.css" />
<div id="facebook"><div class="hidden_elem invisible_elem"></div></div>
```

JavaScript (execute this code after all resources have been loaded):

```
if($("#facebook div").css("display") != "none" || $("#facebook div").css("visibility") != "hidden") disableFBFrame();
// Where disableFBFrame(); is a function which hides the frame.
```

Comment: i saw your code. and edited one iframe as
`<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com"></iframe>`
www.facebook.com this is blocked from my workplace. and the output is showing this iframe saying that the proxy has refused to show the content. :(
What to do?