# How to check if all frames have been loaded?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I need to determine if in a given moment all frames have been loaded and wait if not. This is because I need to call an iframe method when user clicks on a link:

```
for (var i = 0;  i < window.frames.length;  i++) {
    if (window.frames[i].getName() == name) {
       ......
    }
}
```

and it returns the error `window.frames[i].getName is not a function` if user clicks too fast (no time to load).

So I need to check if all frames have been loaded and then if not, wait until it happens. Thanks.

Comment: someone still uses frames? a Tip only: Use jQuery or ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer: [Hide the iframes whose content get blocked by proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7513761/hide-the-iframes-whose-content-get-blocked-by-proxy/7515297#7515297)

The code at that answer does not only show *whether* a frame is loaded or not, but *also* whether the page is successfully loaded or not.