# JavaScript: Working with Frames/iFrames in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, frames

I want to execute JavaScript code once my iFrames or Frames load. document.onReady executes before the frames are rendered on the pages so I cannot use that. Any suggestions?

I found a 3rd party plugin called FrameReady but it does not work in IE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if all frames have been loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752431/how-to-check-if-all-frames-have-been-loaded)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try waiting for window's `load` event, it waits until all iframes have loaded.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // images and iframes have loaded
})
```